# How to putObject without InputStream lenght knowdlege

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, inputstream

I'm using SDK 2.0 and trying to putObject into the bucket.

From different API I'm receiving InputStream which holds file (CSV or plain text)

```
InputStream stream = otherApi.get();

S3Client s3 = S3Client.build(); 

s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder(), RequestBody ? )
```

RequestBody has multiple useful methods as well `RequestBody.fromInputStream` but require to provide `contentLenght` which I don't know. Files could be (1MB or even 20MB).

Anyone faced with this problem during using the new API version?

Old 1.X did not requered knowledge of contentLength.

Comment: Yes, I faced this issue a month ago or so - you will need to calculate the content length before you send it off, API V1 did the exact same. If your file is too big, split into a multi part request in the interest of memory usage when calculating content length.